# Microsoft MVC: trigger form validation manually

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, validation

does anyone know if there is a way to trigger the client side form validation in a .Net MVC app manually? I want to do the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if([form valid]) {
        //do something
    }
</script>
```

I already looked through the code in MicrosoftMvcValidation.js but didn't find a method I could call on the form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the validation you are looking for can be found here:
http://www.phpvs.net/2010/04/26/manually-validate-an-asp-net-mvc-form-on-the-client-side-with-microsoftmvcvalidation-js-and-jquery/

The deal is you need context of Sys.Mvc.FormContext, which has a .validate on it.  This is what needs to be called.  Just check out the blog post and you will be happy.  :-)

Comment: Not anymore...! (`I think the validation you are looking for can be found here`)