# How can I create a form with validation in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am having problems with my submit form. For some reason when I submit the correct answers it gives me error messages for the input. It submits and returns the view with error messages and the text boxes are empty. I want the error messages to disappear once I have enter the correct input.

This is my view:

```
<form method="post">
    <!--form validations-->

    <div class="row mb-2">
        <h2 class="display-4 c-title">Send Us a Message</h2>
        <hr class="my-4">

        <!--Gets the first name-->
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
            <label asp-for="@Model.Name" class="form-label">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Name" class="form-control" id="firstNm" name="firstNmLabel" placeholder="First Name">
            <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="@Model.Name"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
            <label asp-for="@Model.LastName" class="form-label">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.LastName" class="form-control" id="lastNm" name="LastNmLabel" placeholder="Last Name">
            <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="@Model.LastName"></span>
        </div>

        <!--Get-->
    </div>

    <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
            <label asp-for="@Model.PhoneNumber" class="form-label">Phone</label>
            <!--as for help in the input-->
            <input type="text"  asp-for="@Model.PhoneNumber" class="form-control" id="phoneNum" name="phoneNum" placeholder="111-111-1111">
            <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="@Model.PhoneNumber"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
            <label for="inputEmail" class="form-label">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" asp-for="@Model.Email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
            <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="@Model.Email"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Collects address--->
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <div>
            <label asp-for="@Model.Address" class="form-label">Stree Address</label>
            <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Address" class="form-control" id="street" name="street">
            <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="@Model.Address"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label asp-for="@Model.City" class="form-label">City</label>
            <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.City" class="form-control" id="city" name="city" placeholder="City">
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Please provide a valid city.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
            <label asp-for="@Model.State" class="form-label">State</label>
            <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.State"  class="form-control" id="state" name="state" placeholder="State" />
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Please provide a valid state.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
            <label asp-for="@Model.PostalCode" class="form-label">Zip</label>
            <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.PostalCode"  class="form-control" id="zip" name="zip" placeholder="Zip">
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Please provide a valid zip.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--try to put a line here so it separates.-->
    <!--Collects information about us-->
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="@Model.Service" class="form-label">What service are you requesting?</label>

                    <!--check if I can add the asp-for in here.--->
                    <select class="form-select" id="services" name="services" asp-for="@Model.Service">
                        <option value="">Please chose a service</option>
                            <option value="Inspection">Inspection</option>
                            <option value="New Roofing">New Roofing</option>
                            <option value="Roof Repair">Roof Repair</option>
                            <option value="Siding">Siding</option>
                            <option value="Gutters">Gutters</option>
                            <option value="Soffit and Fascia">Soffit and Fascia</option>
                            <option value="Commercial roof">Commercial roof</option>
                    </select>
                     <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="@Model.Service"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="@Model.HearAboutUs" class="form-label">How did you hear about us?</label>
                    <select class="form-select" id="hearUs" name="hearUs" asp-for="@Model.HearAboutUs">
                        <option value="">-Select-</option>
                            <option value="Internet Search">Internet Search</option>
                            <option value="Internet Ad">Internet Ad</option>
                            <option value="Direct Mail">Direct Mail</option>
                            <option value="Yard Sign">Yard Sign</option>
                            <option value="Social Media">Social Media</option>
                            <option value="Referral">Referral</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!--This get a lot of text--->
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="@Model.Message" class="form-label">Message</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.Message" id="message" rows="5" name="message"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--Button to submit information------------------------------------------------------------------>
            <div class="row mb-3">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
                   

                </div>
            </div>

</form>
```

This is my model:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace NewOriginConstruction.Models
{
    public class SendMail
    {
        [Required]
        public string? Name { get; set; }

        public string? LastName { get; set; }
        [Required, EmailAddress]
        public string? Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [RegularExpression(@"^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid phone number in the format XXX-XXX-XXXX.")]
        public string? PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string? Address { get; set; }
        public string? City { get; set; }
        public string? State { get; set; }
        
        public int PostalCode { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string? Service { get; set; }

        public string? HearAboutUs { get; set; }

        public string? Message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Lastly this is my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Contact(SendMail sendMail)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) 
        return View(); 

    // 

    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done following changes

a. The 'name' value of the input fields should match with Model name.
eg.
"name"="**Email**"

```
<input type="email" asp-for="@Model.Email" class="form-control" id="Email" name="**Email**" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
```

b. Send the model back to the view in the controller method.
**return View(sendMail);**

c. Removed the '?' from the required fields. *This is optional*

Below is the working code:

**1st change**

```
 public class SendMail
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string? LastName { get; set; }
        [Required, EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [RegularExpression(@"^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid phone number in the format XXX-XXX-XXXX.")]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string? City { get; set; }
        public string? State { get; set; }

        public int PostalCode { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Service { get; set; }

        public string? HearAboutUs { get; set; }

        public string? Message { get; set; }
    }
```

**2nd change**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Contact(SendMail sendMail)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) 
        return View(sendMail);     

    return View();
}
```

**3rd change**

```
<form method="post">
    <!--form validations-->

    <div class="row mb-2">
        <h2 class="display-4 c-title">Send Us a Message</h2>
        <hr class="my-4">

        <!--Gets the first name-->
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
            <label asp-for="@Model.Name" class="form-label">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Name" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="First Name">
            <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="@Model.Name"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
            <label asp-for="@Model.LastName" class="form-label">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.LastName" class="form-control" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
            <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="@Model.LastName"></span>
        </div>

        <!--Get-->
    </div>

    <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
            <label asp-for="@Model.PhoneNumber" class="form-label">Phone</label>
            <!--as for help in the input-->
            <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.PhoneNumber" class="form-control" id="PhoneNumber" name="PhoneNumber" placeholder="111-111-1111">
            <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="@Model.PhoneNumber"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
            <label for="inputEmail" class="form-label">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" asp-for="@Model.Email" class="form-control" id="Email" name="Email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
            <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="@Model.Email"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Collects address--->
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <div>
            <label asp-for="@Model.Address" class="form-label">Stree Address</label>
            <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.Address" class="form-control" id="street" name="Address">
            <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="@Model.Address"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label asp-for="@Model.City" class="form-label">City</label>
            <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.City" class="form-control" id="city" name="city" placeholder="City">
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Please provide a valid city.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
            <label asp-for="@Model.State" class="form-label">State</label>
            <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.State" class="form-control" id="state" name="state" placeholder="State" />
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Please provide a valid state.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
            <label asp-for="@Model.PostalCode" class="form-label">Zip</label>
            <input type="text" asp-for="@Model.PostalCode" class="form-control" id="zip" name="PostalCode" placeholder="Zip">
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Please provide a valid zip.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--try to put a line here so it separates.-->
    <!--Collects information about us-->
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label asp-for="@Model.Service" class="form-label">What service are you requesting?</label>

            <!--check if I can add the asp-for in here.--->
            <select class="form-select" id="services" name="Service" asp-for="@Model.Service">
                <option value="">Please chose a service</option>
                <option value="Inspection">Inspection</option>
                <option value="New Roofing">New Roofing</option>
                <option value="Roof Repair">Roof Repair</option>
                <option value="Siding">Siding</option>
                <option value="Gutters">Gutters</option>
                <option value="Soffit and Fascia">Soffit and Fascia</option>
                <option value="Commercial roof">Commercial roof</option>
            </select>
            <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="@Model.Service"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label asp-for="@Model.HearAboutUs" class="form-label">How did you hear about us?</label>
            <select class="form-select" id="hearUs" name="HearAboutUs" asp-for="@Model.HearAboutUs">
                <option value="">-Select-</option>
                <option value="Internet Search">Internet Search</option>
                <option value="Internet Ad">Internet Ad</option>
                <option value="Direct Mail">Direct Mail</option>
                <option value="Yard Sign">Yard Sign</option>
                <option value="Social Media">Social Media</option>
                <option value="Referral">Referral</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--This get a lot of text--->
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="@Model.Message" class="form-label">Message</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.Message" id="message" rows="5" name="message"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Button to submit information------------------------------------------------------------------>
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="col-12">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />


        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I had this problem for about a week and could not find a solution. I even asked my former professor but he did not answer me. Thank you so much again!

Answer (score 1):

You did not perform client side validation when submitting data. When the server backend validates the data, a red prompt appears. This is the expected behavior.

But if [client side validation is enabled](https://andrewlock.net/adding-client-side-validation-to-aspnet-core-without-jquery-or-unobtrusive-validation/), then we will not be able to submit the form directly, and the data needs to be validated at the front end before it can be passed to the back end.

So I don't think there is a direct solution, only hardcoded processing using javascript. like below:

[How do I clear MVC client side validation errors when a cancel button is clicked when a user has invalidated a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798427/how-do-i-clear-mvc-client-side-validation-errors-when-a-cancel-button-is-clicked)